# Is it possible to choose Channel Divinity options "on the fly"?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, paladin

If you are a Paladin, are you forced to choose a Channel Divinity option once when you take that feature on your class and then stick with it, or can you choose which option to take when you are using your Channel Divinity feature?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> When you **use** your Channel Divinity, you choose which option to use. You must then finish a short or long rest to use your Channel Divinity again. (PHB p.85, emphasis mine)

So you choose your *Oath* once (when reaching the appropriate class level), each oath gives you two options for Channel Divinity. Of those options you always have the choice of which to use, once per rest.

Answer (score 10):

It's when you use it. Under Channel Divinity on page 85, *before* the descriptions of all the Oaths:

> When you use your Channel Divinity, you choose which option to use.

The Oaths then detail what options you gain when you take that Oath.

Answer (score 4):

You have both options. When you use chanel divinity, you choose which effect happens. Through multiclassing, you could have as many as 5 different options to choose from.

Comment: I think this answer would be improved if you made clear that you mean multiclassing Paladin/Cleric, not that you could multiclass Paladin (Vengeance)/Paladin (Devotion), for instance.