# When does a paladin's Channel Divinity refresh?

Tags: dnd-5e, paladin

So in the PHB it says for Paladins "Channel Divinity" you choose which option to use, you must then finish  a short or long rest to use your channel divinity again.

I'm doing Oath of the Ancients, which has "Nature's Wrath" (an ensnare) and "Turn the Faithless". However neither one says anything about "an option" to do.....so....do these get restored on a long or short rest?

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to choose Channel Divinity options “on the fly”?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/68961/is-it-possible-to-choose-channel-divinity-options-on-the-fly)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### Channel Divinity is a resource that both *Nature's Wrath* and *Turn the Faithless* consume.

As is written in the text for both *Nature's Wrath* and *Turn the Faithless*:

> You can **use your Channel Divinity** to ...

And the Channel Divinity text:

> Your oath allows you to channel divine energy to fuel magical effects. **Each Channel Divinity option** provided by your oath explains how to use it. **When you use your Channel Divinity, you choose which option to use**.
>
> **You must then finish a short or long rest to use your Channel Divinity again.** Some Channel Divinity effects require saving throws. When you use such an effect from this class, the DC equals your paladin spell save DC.

Emphasis mine. Note that Channel Divinity is just a resource that you can spend on different **options**, much like Spells and Spell Slots, and that resource is refreshed on a short or long rest.

Comment: The comparison to spell slots feels very helpful.